# Why doesn't my laptop boot up after swapping my RAM?

Tags: windows-7, memory, motherboard, asus-laptop

I had 4GB (2GBX2) RAM installed on my laptop. I wanted to upgrade my RAM to 8GB. So I bought Kingston HyperX Impact Black 8GB 1600MHz DDR3 Notebook Ram (HX316LS9IB/8). 
http://goo.gl/ZpfAV4 
I used Crucial's scan to get specific information about compatible RAMs (since I don't live in USA, I can't purchase from Crucial's website nor from Kingston and Kingston doesn't have my laptop in its category). Using the information found on the site I purchased the following RAM but it doesn't work. I installed my 8GB RAM. Made sure it is fitted nicely. Computer starts and I can hear the drives running but screen stays black and computer seems to start by itself now and then or fan stops now and then. Nothing comes up. No warning nor any fault messages. What am I doing wrong? Can the RAM be not compatible with my laptop's system?

My laptop is Asus K52JT. But on the RAMs (original RAMs) show this DDR3 2GB-1333 SSZ3128M8-EDJEF .

Edit 1:

So I tried this. I placed one of the 2GB RAMs with 8GB RAM and and checked BIOS. It shows that there is 10GB RAM in total but when Windows boots up it freezes at booting up. Shows starts but nothing comes up and fan heats up. I tried booting only with one 2GB RAM and it does boot.

Comment: Well, the ultimate test is "does it work", as it seems to be failing that test, the ram is most likely incompatible. Are you able to replace the original ram and operate normally?

Comment: @jgritty yes. Old rams do work when i place them back. Is it possible to check if they work either than putting in another laptop

Comment: You need 1333mhz ram as specified by Asus. https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/K52JT/specifications/

Comment: @jgritty
So I tried this. I placed one of the 2GB RAMs with 8GB RAM and and checked BIOS. It shows that there is 10GB RAM in total but when Windows boots up it freezes at booting up. Shows starts but nothing comes up and fan heats up. I tried booting only with one 2GB RAM and it does boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your newly purchased RAM *should* be compatible with the machine, as even if it's faster than the machine can handle it should downclock to a suitable speed.

It's not impossible that a stick is DOA, and it's fairly easy to test if this is the case by trying the machine with one of your 4GB sticks inserted at a time. If it works with one stick and not the other, you've identified a faulty stick and will need to get a replacement.

If it doesn't work with either stick, there is a small possibility that both sticks are faulty, although it's of course quite unlikely, and that machine is for some reason more fussy about it. It may be worth checking if a BIOS update is available for your machine that may improve compatibility, otherwise looking for RAM of equal speeds to the current sticks would be your best chance.

Comment: So I tried this. I placed one of the 2GB RAMs with 8GB RAM and and checked BIOS. It shows that there is 10GB RAM in total but when Windows boots up it freezes at booting up. Shows starts but nothing comes up and fan heats up. I tried booting only with one 2GB RAM and it does boot.

Comment: Sorry - got confused because the link you provided was a 2x4GB kit instead of a single RAM stick. If the RAM was incompatible you shouldn't be able to boot with it in at all. I'm suspicious there's a problem with the RAM you've received.

Comment: owh no. Sorry for confusion. I took that as reference and bought 8GB RAM NOT 4GBx2. Cause I can't order from there. Does this (what I did and the outcome) indicate that the RAM is incompatible? But the ram works right?